# Style not applying

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

I have following file `state.css`. In it, there is this piece of code:

```
    .linked_location .rating {
        position: absolute;
        right: 180px;
        bottom: 2px;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

In my html after the `body` tag, I have the following `styles` **overridden**.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .linked_location .rating {
      position: absolute;
      right: 180px;
      bottom: 2px;
      height: 15px;
    }
    </style>
```

Here is my output HTML : (**Note: I am using`XSLT` and maybe the `style` tag is the issue.**)

```
    <div class="linked_location">
    <div class="rating">
    <div class="score">4.<small>3</small>
    </div>
    <span>Rating</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that It's using the height as `30px` despite me updating the style manually to `15px` in the style tag.

**Not quite sure what the problem is, maybe it has to do with using a style tag in `xslt`**

Comment: I am guessing the order in which the styles are applied is different. The inline style might be applied before the one from the linked stylesheet !? more of HTML might be helpful.

Comment: If you declare a style in `<body>`, you should use this tag: `<style type='text/css' scoped='scoped'>` - otherwise it could be ignored (like in FireFox).

Comment: try adding `!important` to the inline style tag height? `height: 15px !important;`

Answer (score -1):

try it in your CSS:

```
height: 30px!important;
```